# Ruby dup/clone recursively

Tags: ruby, hash, clone, hash-of-hashes, dup

I have a hash like:

```
h = {'name' => 'sayuj', 
     'age' => 22, 
     'project' => {'project_name' => 'abc', 
                   'duration' => 'prq'}}
```

I need a dup of this hash, the change should not affect the original hash.

When I try,

```
d = h.dup # or d = h.clone
d['name'] = 'sayuj1'
d['project']['duration'] = 'xyz'

p d #=> {"name"=>"sayuj1", "project"=>{"duration"=>"xyz", "project_name"=>"abc"}, "age"=>22}
p h #=> {"name"=>"sayuj", "project"=>{"duration"=>"xyz", "project_name"=>"abc"}, "age"=>22}
```

Here you can see the `project['duration']` is changed in the original hash because `project` is another hash object.

I want the hash to be `duped` or `cloned` recursively. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here's how you make deep copies in Ruby

```
d = Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(h) )
```

Comment: This creates full copies of all objects referenced by `h`. This might be exactly what is needed by Sayuj for simple String hashes. With more complex objects, this might not be desired anymore. Once could override the `Hash#dup` method to dup all hashes in `values` recursively. But that would need to be extended for every object type.

Comment: @HolgerJust: yes, that's why it's called a "deep copy" :-)

Comment: Of course. I just wanted to mention that it might do more than the OP intended (although it's probably just fine) :) So it's just for, well, future reference.

Comment: Note that this will not work when there is a default proc (e.g. `h = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = 1}`)

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Rails: [Hash.deep_dup](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_dup)

Answer (score 2):

In case the `Marchal` `#dump/load` pair isn't work, for [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) there is a `Hash`'s method `#deep_dup`, so you can:

```
h = {'name' => 'sayuj', 
 'age' => 22, 
 'project' => {'project_name' => 'abc', 
               'duration' => 'prq'}}

h1 = h.deep_dup
```

Comment: the method should be h.deep_dup instead of h.deep.dup

Comment: `deep_dup` method will turn a Class into anonymous Class, not recommended.

Comment: @TianChen example?

Comment: see this example:
    `class Abc; end`
    `h = { 'class' => Abc }`
    `h1 = h.deep_dup # => => {"class"=>#<Class:0x0000000abe50a0>}`

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to a reasonably old question, but I happened upon it while implementing something similar, thought I'd chime in for a more efficient method.

For the simple, two level deep hash like above, you can also do something like this:

```
d = h.inject({}) {|copy, (key, value)| 
    copy[key] = value.dup rescue value; copy
}
```

I ran a test on a hash of hashes with 4k elements, each a few hundred bytes, and it was about 50% faster than the Marshal.dump/load

Of course, it's not as complete, as it won't work if you have a hash as, e.g., the value of the 'project_name' field, but for a simple 2 level hash, it works great / faster.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the full_dup gem (full disclosure: I am the author of that gem) that handles arrays, hashes, structs, and is extendable to user defined classes.

To use:

```
require 'full_dup'
# Other code omitted ...
d = h.full_dup
```

Also note that full_dup handles complex data relationships including those with loops or recursion.