# Keeping the values of two variables from `each` method

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
session={"apple"=>["bp", "80APPM", "donald"]}
@like_list = session
@like_list.each do |key, value|
  value.each_with_index do |v, i|
    @like_list[key][i] = 2
  end
end
session    # => {"apple"=>[2, 2, 2]}
@like_list # => {"apple"=>[2, 2, 2]}
```

The object assigned to the variables `session` and `@like_list` are both changed. Is there any way to perform the above code without changing the value of `session`?

I tried using `clone` and `dup` but no change

Comment: dup and clone are shallow copies, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4157635/3109182

Comment: @sawa, sorry, a typo. it should be "@like_list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Hash.deep_dup`.

```
@like_list = session.deep_dup
```

[Here is the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_dup) for the method.

EDIT:

This method comes from `activesupport` library, which is included with Rails. As suggested in the comments, this method used to be problematic, but [as of Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activesupport/CHANGELOG.md), it behaves more expectedly. I tested the above example and it works with `activesupport 4.2.3`.

If you are not using Rails, you need to load [activesupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/):

```
require 'active_support'
```

Comment: Hash#deep_dup doesn't work with contained arrays.  Try it out and see.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Which ruby version are you using? I'm running 2.3.0 and it works

Comment: Ruby 2.2.5, 2.1.9, and 1.9.3, and none of them work.  It must be fixed in the new one.  That bug has been around for ages and ages...

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.3 and Rails 4. deep_dup method works for me. Both variable values are kept. Thanks!

Comment: You have, imo, answered a question that wasn't asked. In the absence of a specification that `session["apple"]` can have multiple levels of nesting, and the fact that the given value does not have nesting, we should assume there is no nesting, in which case loading `activesupport` (note no Rails tag) is overkill. It's fine to show how nesting could be dealt with, but only as an aside.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a copy of the original hash, to prevent two variables reference the same object.

```
@like_list = session.map { |key, value| [key, value.clone] }.to_h
```

Comment: This method works for a single-level hash, but if there are any nested levels, those below the top level will still be shallow copied.  To make this work, you need to handle arbitrary levels of nesting.

Comment: @Michael, the question did not specify multiple levels of nesting, and the specified value of `session` has but one, so this answer is fine, preferable to methods that permit arbitrary levels of nesting.

Comment: My comment was simply intended as a warning to anyone that tries to use this in the general case.  Questions and answers have a long lifetime on SO.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
session={"apple"=>["bp", "80APPM", "donald"]}
@like_list = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(session))
@like_list.each do |key, value|
  value.each_with_index do |v, i|
    @like_list[key][i] = 2
  end
end
```

It uses the `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(session))` solution from this SO question: [Ruby dup/clone recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710642/ruby-dup-clone-recursively)

Comment: `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(session)).each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = [2]*v.size }` or `@like_list = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(session)).tap { |h| h.each { |k,v| h[k] = [2]*v.size } }`, but as I've indicated in other comments, I don't think the question calls for a deep dup.