# How can i duplicate a record with ruby (outside of rails)?

Tags: ruby

I have a hash with an object id of 19475160, I need to clone my hash, how would I go about doing this? Every google search and article I have found points me to rails solutions but I cant find anything that is a regular ruby solution.

Comment: Do you want a deep copy of a variable?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710642/ruby-dup-clone-recursively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do a shallow copy of an object:

```
 obj2 = obj.clone
```

This will do a deep copy of an object:

```
  obj2 = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(obj))
```

Comment: thanks, for my own knowledge can I ask what the difference is between a shallow copy and a deep copy?

Comment: @alilland Unlike shallow copy, deep copy will also copy any referenced objects in your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dup`.

```
h = {a:1}
h2 = h.dup
h[:a] = 2
h2
=> {:a=>1}
```

`h` and `h2` have different object_id's.

From [dup reference](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-dup):

> Produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are copied, but not the objects they reference.